# Error installing mysql 'OSError: mysql_config not found'

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, linux, pip

Working in a AWS SageMaker notebook (Kernel PyTorch 1.8 Python 3.6 GPU optimized), I get errors when installing mysql and mysqlclient using commands:

```
!python3 -m pip install mysql
!python3 -m pip install mysqlclient
```

Both give about the same error message:

```
Collecting mysql
  Using cached mysql-0.0.3-py3-none-any.whl (1.2 kB)
Collecting mysqlclient
  Using cached mysqlclient-2.1.0.tar.gz (87 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /opt/conda/bin/python3 -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-uhwwzugv/mysqlclient_3db23749deac4d49af5f203f20638373/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-uhwwzugv/mysqlclient_3db23749deac4d49af5f203f20638373/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-rhc6np1s
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-uhwwzugv/mysqlclient_3db23749deac4d49af5f203f20638373/
  Complete output (15 lines):
  mysql_config --version
  /bin/sh: 1: mysql_config: not found
  mariadb_config --version
  /bin/sh: 1: mariadb_config: not found
  mysql_config --libs
  /bin/sh: 1: mysql_config: not found
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/tmp/pip-install-uhwwzugv/mysqlclient_3db23749deac4d49af5f203f20638373/setup.py", line 15, in <module>
      metadata, options = get_config()
    File "/tmp/pip-install-uhwwzugv/mysqlclient_3db23749deac4d49af5f203f20638373/setup_posix.py", line 70, in get_config
      libs = mysql_config("libs")
    File "/tmp/pip-install-uhwwzugv/mysqlclient_3db23749deac4d49af5f203f20638373/setup_posix.py", line 31, in mysql_config
      raise OSError("{} not found".format(_mysql_config_path))
  OSError: mysql_config not found
```

I've tried previously installing mysql using a wheel file but even though the install didn't spit any error I then got the message

```
ImportError: cannot import name '_mysql'
```

when creating an optuna study, so went back to reinstalling mysql.

Comment: Fenced code blocks in Markdown are defined with three _backticks_ (`\``), not single quotes (`'`).

Comment: And please search before asking a new question. There are _several_ existing posts about missing `mysql_config`.